# can't import class src/test/java into src/main/java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am using gradle in eclipse.
I want to use class in src/test/java/testing inside src/main/java/program.

I tried doing :

```
// in program.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final testing t = new testing();

// in testing.java
public class testing {
    ... some code ...
}
```

but the execution failed because it couldn't find symbol "class testing".

I do not see any problem in my program, so I am assuming that I did not properly set the environment up.

I've seen a post saying I have to build path but it says there's no action available.

Can someone help me set the environment up on mac?

Comment: You can import class from main to test. But you can't do it opposite because code in test package is just for testing.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this it would be possible to do with Gradle Java plugin as you can specify your source sets like described here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:changing_java_project_layout but then you would also need to import all the dependencies for implementation configuration. Basically its against convention and probably you just need to see how to run main class and tests separately.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use class in src/test/java/testing inside src/main/java/program.

No, that's not how it's supposed to go. Gradle, eclipse, or for that matter *any* build system and *any* IDE will fight you.

Test code depends on main code, but main code does not depend on test code. It wouldn't work - test code is not shipped when you deploy your application.

If you want to write some tests that you run from main, put that code **in `src/main` itself**. `src/test` is for automated testing purposes.

If you are making a class for some data tracking that the actual test code will use, and currently this tracking class lives in `src/test` because you feel that is where it should go, given that it is test related - move that class to main. Anything that `src/main/...` uses, is by definition 'main' code.